# incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to Tab

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to get a `Tab` from my application like this:

```
searchTab = (Tab)scene.lookup("#searchTab");
```

But I am getting this error:

> incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to Tab

Both of these work:

```
settingsButton = (Button)scene.lookup("#settingsButton");
searchBox = (AnchorPane)scene.lookup("#searchBox");
```

It works with all other types of components, why isn't it working with `Tab`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the tab, I am able to use `getTabs()` and then select the tab id with `get()`

This example demonstrates that:

```
tabPane = (TabPane)scene.lookup("#tabPane");
tabPane.getTabs().get(0).setGraphic(searchiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Tab` is not `Node` (doesn't extends it anyway), so you cannot convert it. To say, what is actual type of `searchTab`, output `searchTab.getClass().getName()` in runtime.

Comment: Okay, so I can do `tabPane = (TabPane)Browser.scene.lookup("#tabPane");` and then use the method `getTabs().get(0)`

Comment: Please, add your answer as answer and mark at is solution, because my answer is just a hint, not a solution, while your's is the whole solution.